# Export Excel Worksheet Range to PDF Error

Tags: vba, excel, pdf

I am trying to write a script that exports a cell range selection to PDF.
The code I have written is the following:

```
Sub ExporttoPDF()

With Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J100")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\Export.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End With

End Sub
```

Everytime I run the script I get a pop-up message with an error that reads: "Run-time error '1004': Document not saved. The document may be open, or an error may have been encountered when saving."

I have researched online and tried to find a solution but wasn't able to. Do you have any idea of what I might be doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Please don't downvote questions, without leaving a supporting comment.  If there is a valid reason it cannot be fixed unless you tell us what it is.  If your reasons are not valid we cannot debate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the clearest of error messages.  The most likely cause is you do have write permissions on the `C:\Users` folder.  This is normally limited to administrator accounts.

I tested the following using a non-admin account:

1. C:\Users\Test.pdf
2. C:\Users\*My-Username*\Test.pdf

The first raised the same error you encountered.  The second worked.

Comment: That was it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: A downvote?  How can the right answer be wrong!?  Please feel free to update with comments, whoever you are.  How else will people learn?

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer. Quite on the contrary!

Comment: Hey @franciscofcosta.  That comment was not aimed at you!  Sorry I should have been cleared in my comments.  I can see that your question was also downvoted by someone (not me).  That made me cross, as I cannot see anything wrong with what you asked.  In fact I upvoted it.

Comment: Hey @destination-data. Just wanted to make sure you knew it hadn't been me! Youre were super helpful. Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has something to do with Excel not being allowed to write to that area?  I'm still looking but I was able to get it to work by changing the path.

```
Sub ExporttoPDF()

With Sheets("Results").Range("B10:J100")
    .ExportAsFixedFormat _
    Type:=xlTypePDF, _
    Filename:="C:\Users\tjb1\Desktop\Export.pdf", _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
End With

End Sub
```